# How to improve DataFrame UDF Which is Connecting to Hbase For every Row

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a DataFrame where I need to create a column based on Values from Each row. 
I iterate using UDF which process for each row and connects to HBase to get Data.

The UDF creates a connection, Returns Data,  Closes a connection.

The process is slow as Zookeeper Hangs after few reads. I want to Pull data with only 1 open connection.

I tried mapwithpartition, But the connection is not passed as it's not serialized.

UDF:-

```
val lookUpUDF = udf((partyID: Int, brand: String, algorithm: String, bigPartyProductMappingTableName: String, env: String) => lookUpLogic.lkpBigPartyAccount(partyID, brand, algorithm, bigPartyProductMappingTableName, env))
```

How DataFrame Iterates:-

```
ocisPreferencesDF
      .withColumn("deleteStatus", lookUpUDF(col(StagingBatchConstants.OcisPreferencesPartyId),
        col(StagingBatchConstants.OcisPreferencesBrand), lit(EnvironmentConstants.digest_algorithm), lit
        (bigPartyProductMappingTableName), lit(env)))
```

Main Login:-

```
def lkpBigPartyAccount(partyID: Int,
                         brand: String,
                         algorithm: String,
                         bigPartyProductMappingTableName: String,
                         envVar: String,
                         hbaseInteraction: HbaseInteraction = new HbaseInteraction,
                         digestGenerator: DigestGenerator = new DigestGenerator): Array[(String, String)] = {
    AppInit.setEnvVar(envVar)
    val message = partyID.toString + "-" + brand
    val rowKey = Base64.getEncoder.encodeToString(message.getBytes())
    val hbaseAccountInfo = hbaseInteraction.hbaseReader(bigPartyProductMappingTableName, rowKey, "cf").asScala
    val convertMap: mutable.HashMap[String, String] = new mutable.HashMap[String, String]
    for ((key, value) <- hbaseAccountInfo) {
      convertMap.put(key.toString, value.toString)
    }

    convertMap.toArray
  }
```

I expect to improve the code performance. What I'm hoping is to create a connection only once.